# Boxplot showing I have NAs although there is no NAs in the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, na

I am trying to see the difference between two groups of cancer patients, Response group and NoResponse group, based on cellular structure of the samples.

It is showing those two classes, along with `NA`, although there are no NAs at all in the data.

##### For example, here I'm trying to see how much T-cells does each group has. `metadata$Response` contains the labels, `Response` / `NoResponse`. `scores.batch` is the data showing the cellular structure of each sample (including, for example here, the `CD4+ memory T-cells`).

```
Temp <- data.frame(sample = colnames(scores.batch), response = metadata$Response)

scores.batch %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("sample") %>% 
  right_join(Temp, .) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = response, y = `CD4+ memory T-cells`)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = response)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','lightblue')) +
  geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.8, alpha=0.9) +
  ylim(0, 0.35)
```

##### The result boxplot:

[image]

Where is this NA coming from? all samples have the same features.. (the `CD4+ memory T-cells` is just one of the features, and it is found for all samples). There is also no NAs in the metadata, and here is a double check. I tried droplevels but didn't work..

```
> table(metadata$Response)

NoResponse   Response 
       976        578
```

##### Here is a sample of `scores.batch`:

```
structure(c(0.014883004488488, 0.0800049305460533, 0.119043918599858, 
0.0532363983028929, 0.0209261095324558, 0.030883271872155, 0.00837497505212542, 
0.206146305909711, 0.0192193854734818, 0.0494657798804256, 0.014883004488488, 
0.0376850764725961, 0.225612302707065, 0.00499966569638846, 0.0209261095324558, 
-0.000239685561631444, 0.00837497505212542, -0.024620418652091, 
0.0199400484281078, 0.0153956758279052, 0.014883004488488, 1.23476056366292, 
0.174539044569868, 0.285623431490223, 0.216380931813251, 0.151288033380354, 
0.0266381085259505, 0.38344530718027, 0.0488466059949254, 0.328647497790061, 
0.014883004488488, 0.169685267401814, 0.705958815914031, 0.00499966569638846, 
0.0209261095324558, -0.000239685561631444, 0.00837497505212542, 
0.24259676264725, 0.0270399940617479, 0.0471469401817325, 0.0213169111529152, 
0.0318711357820114, 0.105948939315583, 0.0133957903579662, 0.0209261095324558, 
-0.000239685561631444, 0.00837497505212542, 0.111171710498514, 
0.0368583750761783, 0.03992795719113, 0.0711618323825095, 0.0317513362548736, 
0.589283068146178, 0.00499966569638846, 0.0209261095324558, -0.000239685561631444, 
0.00837497505212542, -0.024620418652091, 0.0142621299834546, 
0.0153956758279052, 0.014883004488488, 0.0120147886060005, 0.16730380132951, 
0.00499966569638846, 0.0209261095324558, -0.000239685561631444, 
0.00837497505212542, -0.024620418652091, 0.0214275647170159, 
0.0153956758279052, 0.014883004488488, 0.618090130272143, 0.0789942435186591, 
0.0796575218515729, 0.0272938950883872, 0.0304703814593178, 0.00837497505212542, 
0.241356282324198, 0.0144661637543188, 0.127987668126863, 0.014883004488488, 
0.0573847408296657, 0.165201521137427, 0.0185917511199549, 0.0209261095324558, 
0.0119573761240307, 0.00837497505212542, 0.110914788002896, 0.0163382992787417, 
0.0275740999415521, 0.195674400348798, 0.201269251609304, 0.10888229184014, 
0.0591809435391309, 0.0209261095324558, -0.000239685561631444, 
0.00837497505212542, 0.190401963339481, 0.0158741086027058, 0.0377363431850158
), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(c("Adipocytes", "B-cells", 
"Basophils", "CD4+ memory T-cells", "CD4+ naive T-cells", "CD4+ T-cells", 
"CD4+ Tcm", "CD4+ Tem", "CD8+ naive T-cells", "CD8+ T-cells"), 
    c("Pt1", "Pt10", "Pt101", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17", 
    "Pt18", "Pt2", "Pt24")))
```

##### Metadata:

```
structure(list(dataset = c("Riaz.SKCM", "Riaz.SKCM", "Riaz.SKCM", 
"Riaz.SKCM", "Riaz.SKCM", "Riaz.SKCM", "Riaz.SKCM", "Riaz.SKCM", 
"Riaz.SKCM", "Riaz.SKCM"), samples = c("Pt1", "Pt10", "Pt101", 
"Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", "Pt24"), Response = c("NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", "NoResponse", 
"NoResponse", "Response", "NoResponse", "NoResponse"), RECIST = c("PD", 
"SD", "PR", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PR", "SD", "PD"), Cancer_Type = c("Melanoma", 
"Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", 
"Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma"), CR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Where is `metadata`?

Comment: @Quinten I added a sample.

Comment: When I run your code, there are no `NAs`. Please try with clean environment?

Comment: Like @Quinten, I get no NA values when I run your code with the data you provided. We can therefore only guess what might be going on. My guess would be that changing `as.data.frame()` to `as.data.frame(check.names = FALSE)` will fix your problem.

Comment: @AllanCameron it didn't work. My data is too large, I can't `dput` it all here. This is very weird it never happened to me before..

Comment: The problem is that you are ending up with NA values after the right join. Instead of passing the result of the right join, store the result and examine it. There will be NA values in the response column in some of the rows where no join was made. Look at these rows and find out why no join was made.